# Update multiple rows in one query

Tags: database, wpdb

I want to update multiple rows in one query using wpdb->update. I get no error in the [debug.log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) file but only the last row is updated.

```
$my_update = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'my_settings',
            array( 'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp,
                   'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp_host,
                   'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp_auth ),
            array( 'name' => 'mail-smtp',
                   'name' => 'mail-smtp-host',
                   'name' => 'mail-smtp-auth' ) );
```

The table structure is (eg):

```
id - name - value
1 - mail-smtp - yes
2 - mail-smtp-host - smtp.domain.tld
3 - mail-smtp-auth - yes
```

I want to update the `value` at `name`. Am i doing something wrong?

**Update:**

With `$wpdb->last_query;` i get `UPDATE settings SET value = 0 WHERE name = mail-smtp-auth` It seems like he not even recognize the other. `$wpdb->last_result` and `$wpdb->last_error` are both empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled a lot the last days and a few times i´ve seen postings that say that the `$wpdb->update` function doens´t support multiple updates and that this is not well documented. -> Sorry i don´t have links anymore...

I think that this is true because i couldn´t get it to work and i found not a single example witch works this way. So i use this way now to update multiple rows and still be able to handle errors.

The function:

```
function update_queries( $queries ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // set array
    $error = array();

    // run update commands
    foreach( $queries as $query ) {
        $query = str_replace( '[wp-prefix]', $wpdb->prefix, $query );
        $last_error = $wpdb->last_error;
        $wpdb->query( $query );

        // fill array when we have an error
        if( (empty( $wpdb->result ) || !$wpdb->result ) && !empty( $wpdb->last_error ) && $last_error != $wpdb->last_error ) {
                $error[]= $wpdb->last_error." ($query)";
        }
    }

    // when we have an error
    if( $error ) {
        return $error;

    // when everything is fine
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If we want to update a few things:

```
// update database
$queries = array();
$queries[] = "UPDATE `[wp-prefix]table` SET `value` = '$value'  WHERE `name` = 'name';";
$queries[] = "UPDATE `[wp-prefix]table` SET `value` = '$value2'  WHERE `name` = 'name2';";
$error = update_queries( $queries );

// if we have an error
if( !empty( $error ) ) {
    .....

// when everything is fine
}else{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks okay. My guess is your first two variables are empty.

Try hardcoding in values to see if those save.

```
$tmp_mail_smtp      = 'Test Mail SMTP';
$tmp_mail_smtp_host = 'Test Mail SMTP Host';
$tmp_mail_smtp_auth = 'Test Mail SMTP Auth';

$my_update = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'my_settings',
    array( 'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp,
           'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp_host,
           'value' => $tmp_mail_smtp_auth,
    ),
    array( 'name' => 'mail-smtp',
           'name' => 'mail-smtp-host',
           'name' => 'mail-smtp-auth',
    )
);
```

**Update #1**

Since the above doesn't work for you, remove the `$wpdb->update` code and try updating each option separately and see if that works.

```
if ( $settings_message == '0' ) {
  update_option( 'role', $tmp_role );
  update_option( 'mail-smtp', $tmp_mail_smtp );
  update_option( 'mail-smtp-host', $tmp_mail_smtp_host );
  update_option( 'mail-smtp-auth', $tmp_mail_smtp_auth );
}
```

P.S. Since this is a wp-admin page, I'd read more about the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) which provides a more structured way of adding/managing option pages.

Comment: Even if i do this only the last one is updated. If i delete the last one only the second (now the last again) is updated.

Comment: What `add_action` are you using to trigger this or where are you calling this? Could you update your code above to include more?

Comment: You can find the whole code here: http://paste.ofcode.org/345EKB5MKsGffd6DUgLEdh3 It´s too large to paste it here.

Comment: With `$wpdb->last_query;` i get `UPDATE settings SET value = 0 WHERE name = mail-smtp-auth` It seems like he not even recognize the other. `$wpdb->last_result` and `$wpdb->last_error` are both empty.

Comment: @wassereimer Thanks for the code link. Didn't realize it was code in wp-admin. I've updated my answer above so try that.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the settings api... But.... This isn´t really a solution for my problem..... :D I have a lot of things ready to work with the database.... Changing everything is not a option. :)